# is control panel program list is similar to the win32_product list...?

Tags: wmi, wmi-query

My task is to list all the software programs that are installed in my desktop.

will i use the win32_product for displaying this list.

will the following query works for this...?

```
select * from win32_product;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`Win32_Product`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class **only list the software installed by the Windows Installer**. AFAIK there is not another WMI class to list all the installed software, So you best  option is use the Uninstall Registry Key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```